# Is a Distribution Exponential if its Mean equals its Standard Deviation

Tags: exponential-function

Can someone clarify if it is safe to declare that a distribution is not exponential if the mean and standard deviation are not equal, for example coefficient of variance, c < 1 and that it is exponential if c = 1.

The question is based on the argument that if this is indeed true then why are there so many tests out there that test the hypothesis?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Counter Example: $X \sim N(1,1)$

So, the answer is no. Just because a distribution's mean and standard deviation are identical it does not follow that the distribution is an exponential.

Comment: Thankyou. However does it follow then that if the mean and standard deviation are not equal then categorically it is not exponentially distributed?

Comment: The answer is yes as long as the means and standard deviation are population measures and not based on sample data.

Comment: Agree.  Many thanks.